# set a particular listbox item as selected in html through jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, listbox

i m new to jsp, what want to do is:
to set a listbox item as selected in html from jsp

in abc.jsp

```
<%  
try  
{  
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dsnName","","");  
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();  
    String query="select * from tablen1 where id=1";  
    ResultSet rset=stmt.executeQuery(query);//suppose only one record is selected or fetched  
    String data=rset.getString(2);//i want this value to be shown in listbox of html form as selected when that form get opened  
    ..............  
    ......  
%> 

<form>  
 .......  
 ......  
 <select  name="paper" onBlur="f_papper();" >   
    <option value="">---SELECT---</option>  
    <option value="value1">item1</option>  
    <option value="value2">item2</option>  
    <option value="value3">item3</option>  
    <option value="value4">item4</option>  
    <option value="value5">item5</option>  
    <option value="value6">item6</option>  
    <option value="value7">item7</option>  
 </select>  
</form>
```

plz tell me how can i make a listbox item as selected according to my need..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please refer [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below < select > of before < /body >

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('paper').value = '<%= data %>';
</script>
```

as suggested by @s3ib

OR

```
<select  name="paper" onBlur="f_papper();" >   
<option value="">---SELECT---</option> 
<option value="value1" <%if("value1".equals(data)out.print("selected='selected'");%>>item1</option>

 <option value="value2"    <%if("value2".equals(data)out.print("selected='selected'");%>>item2</option>
...
</select>
```

The above code is ideal if you are generating the options using loop

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="paper" id="paper" onBlur="f_papper();" >
  <option value="">---SELECT---</option>
  <option value="value1">item1</option>
  <option value="value2">item2</option>
  <option value="value3">item3</option>
  <option value="value4">item4</option>
  <option value="value5">item5</option>
  <option value="value6">item6</option>
  <option value="value7">item7</option>
</select>

<script>
  $('#paper').val('<%= data %>');
</script>
```

This would be one way of doing it using jQuery.

**EDITED:**
Or if you dont want to use jQuery, you can use pure JavaScript also like that:

```
<script>
   document.getElementById('paper').value = '<%= data %>';
</script>
```

Comment: thanks @Tarmo i really get the task done..by ur help

Answer (score 0):

```
<select  name="paper"  >   
    <option value="">---SELECT---</option>  
    <option value="value1" selected="">item1</option>  //this value selected
    <option value="value2" >item2</option>  
    <option value="value3">item3</option>  
    <option value="value4">item4</option>  
    <option value="value5">item5</option>  
    <option value="value6">item6</option>  
    <option value="value7">item7</option>  
 </select>
```

this tips may help you...